# Laravel sum eloquent collection

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, calculated-field

How can i sum a data set that has been eager loaded?

This is my table structure:

```
regions table
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| region     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

submits table
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| region_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| deals      | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

These are my models / relationships :-

```
class Region extends Eloquent {

  public function submits()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Submit');
  }

}

<?php

class Submit extends Eloquent {

  public function regions()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Region');
  }
  
}
```

This is my controller

```
  public function index()
  {
    $regions = Region::with('submits')->get();

    return $regions;
    //return View::make('pages.index', compact('regions'));
  }
```

This is what the returned data looks like (in json format, i understand $regions in an eloquent collection):-

[image: raw json]

I can't figure out how i can send the sum total of 'deals' (4) back to the view?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$deals = $regions->sum(function ($region) {
    return $region->submits->sum('deals');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show this [package](https://github.com/Alexmg86/laravel-sub-query)

```php
$invoices = Region::withSum('submits:deals')->get();
```